# Como eliminar el salto de linea luego de un Scanf en C

Tags: c, scanf

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para la facultad en la que toma un arreglo y verifica que todos sus elementos sean positivos. Pero pido los elementos del arreglo, al usar `scanf`, me da salto de lineas después de introducir cada valor del arreglo (quería saber como solucionarlo manteniendo el `scanf`).

La parte de mi código encargado de pedir los valores del arreglo es este:

```
printf ("Por ultimo necesito saber los valores del arreglo: \n");
int a[tam];
for (int i = 0;i<tam;i++){
    scanf (" %d",&a[i]);
}
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es limpiar el búfer?, si es así, agrega este código después de llamar a `scanf`: `while(getchar() != '\n');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es de `scanf` sino de cómo está implementada la entrada estándar en C. En C, las operaciones sobre la entrada estándar bloquean la ejecución del programa hasta que se introduce un salto de línea. Nota que no es necesario introducir un salto de línea para cada lectura... basta con un salto de línea final.

Por explicarlo con un poco más de detalle: cada vez que se pide leer un valor, `scanf` comprueba si la el buffer de entrada está vacío o no. Si lo está se bloqueará hasta que le llegue la señal correspondiente para empezar a leer, como podrás adivinar, esta señal se lanza cuando se presiona la tecla *enter*. Si resulta que el uffer de entrada no está vacío entonces procederá a leer el dato pedido y lo devolverá.

Una forma de comprobar esta funcionalidad es con un ejemplo como el siguiente:

```
int main(void)
{
  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
    int numero;
    scanf("%d", numero);
    printf("%d ", numero);
  }
}
```

Este programa tan sofisticado, que se limita a leer 10 números para mostrarlos nuevamente por pantalla, podemos ejecutarlo de varias formas diferentes:

- metemos un número, pulsamos enter, y repetimos el proceso 9 veces más
- metemos un número, introducimos un espacio (o varios) y procedemos de igual manera con los 9 números restantes... introducimos un enter final para que el programa continúe.
- Mezclamos los dos puntos anteriores como mejor nos parezca.

Pues bien, eso lo tenemos de cara a la entrada estándar... pero es que resulta que, de acuerdo con el estándar, los datos introducidos por la entrada estándar producen, automáticamente, un eco en la salida estándar.

Es decir, por un lado el estándar nos obliga a introducir un *enter* y, por otro, nos va a hacer un echo de dicha tecla en la salida estándar... por lo que el salto de línea va a aparecer en la pantalla queramos o no.

**¿Y no hay nada que se pueda hacer?**

Por supuesto que si. La funcionalidad ofrecida por la librería estándar no es excluyente, es decir, nada te impide hablar directamente con la API del Sistema Operativo para conseguir tus propósitos. Es un proceso bastante engorroso pero funciona, que es lo importante.

Por otro lado, puedes acudir a librerías de terceros, ellos ya se han pegado con este problema y te encapsulan la complejidad de la API con una interfaz (a veces) más amigable. A modo de ejemplo, una alternativa podría ser [ncurses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Pero insisto, tirando única y exclusivamente de la librería estándar, lo que quieres hacer no tiene solución.